# Type 'Any' has no subscript members in swift3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

```
Alamofire.request(Config.recommendationURL, headers: headers).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            if (swiftyJsonVar["success"]).boolValue {
                if let recommendData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                    var j = 0
                    for source in recommendData  {
                        if j < 2 {
                            let rcmId = source["_id"]!! as! String
                            j = j + 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why I got following error when I've installed XCode8. Above is complete code of mine.

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members in swift3

Comment: The compiler doesn't (but has to) know the type of `source`. Not related, but you're using too many exclamation marks.

Comment: @user28434 it's quite different.

Comment: @ppshein, core problem is same

Comment: Basically it's not different: The compiler **must** know the types of all objects which are subscripted by key or index. Cast `recommendData` to `[[String:Any]]` and remove the two exclamation marks after `source["_id"]`